# Dynamically adding Page size dropdown list in the Gridview Pager

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu, using-statement

I have a Gridview for which Dropdown list has to be added on the run time at the Pager row. I have added the below code on the Gridview RowCreated.

```
protected void gv_transaction_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Pager)
    {
        using (DropDownList ddlpagesize = new DropDownList())
        {
            ddlpagesize.Items.Add("25");
            ddlpagesize.Items.Add("50");
            ddlpagesize.Items.Add("75");
            ddlpagesize.Items.Add("100");
            ddlpagesize.Items.Add("150");
            ddlpagesize.Items.Add("200");
            ddlpagesize.AutoPostBack = true;
            ddlpagesize.Items.FindByText(gv_transaction.PageSize.ToString()).Selected = true;
            ddlpagesize.SelectedIndexChanged += ddlpagesize_SelectedIndexChanged;
            using (Table tbl = (Table)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0])
            {
                using (TableCell cell = new TableCell())
                {
                    cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<b>Page Size: </b>"));
                    cell.Controls.Add(ddlpagesize);
                    tbl.Rows[0].Cells.AddAt(0, cell);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
protected void ddlpagesize_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (DropDownList ddlpagesize = (DropDownList)sender)
    {
        gv_transaction.PageSize = int.Parse(ddlpagesize.SelectedValue);
        gv_transaction.PageIndex = 0;
        BindTransactionGrid();
    }
}
```

Now, SelectedIndex change event is not firing, when I change the dropdownlist value. 
But interestingly, when I remove the using statement from the initiation of page size Dropdownlist; Selectedindex event is firing perfectly. Please tell me if there is any relation with the disposing of dropdownlist and selectedIndex Changed event for the dynamic dropdown in a Gridview

Comment: Why do you want to dispose the only just created DropDownList and why do you think that this wouldn't have sideeffects? You are disposing the object before it's persisted in ViewState and therefore it won't raise any events on postbacks.

Comment: As a good programming habit, we have to dispose the control created dynamically. isn't it?

Comment: ASP.NET-Controls are disposed automatically at the end of the [Page-Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx), hence you shouldn't dispose them manually. Actually the complete page will be disposed after the HTML is rendered and sent to the client(HTTP is stateless).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to wrap asp.net controls in using statements, asp.net will call dispose automatically on your controls, i think your using statements are causing them to be disposed too early.